# PHP Nested ifs and many conditions not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have many nested ifs and conditions in my code but it is not giving the  desired output. What is the  best way to write the following code :

```
$driver_code = $this->input->post('filter_driver_code');

        $unit_code = $this->input->post('filter_unit_code');

        $fuel_type = $this->input->post('filter_fuel');

        $date_to = $this->input->post('date_to');

        $date_from = $this->input->post('date_from');





        if (isset($date_from) and isset($date_to) and empty($unit_code) and empty($driver_code) and empty($fuel_type)) {

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM fuel_usage where (date between '$date_from' and '$date_to') ";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        } elseif (isset($driver_code) and isset($unit_code) and isset($fuel_type) and isset($date_from) and isset($date_to)) {

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM fuel_usage where driver_code='$driver_code' AND unit_code='$unit_code' AND fuel_type='$fuel_type' and (date between '$date_from' and '$date_to')";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        }  elseif (empty ($date_from) and empty ($date_to) and isset ($unit_code) and isset ($driver_code) and isset ($fuel_type)) {

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM fuel_usage where driver_code='$driver_code' AND unit_code='$unit_code' AND fuel_type='$fuel_type'";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        }  else {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM FUEL_USAGE";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        }
```

It does not give the  right output.

Comment: Then maybe you should try `var_dump`ing your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try all check with `empty()` may be isset() gives you problem cause on post isset for all variable will return true even values blank

```
       if (!empty($driver_code) && !empty($unit_code) && !empty($fuel_type) && !empty($date_from) && !empty($date_to)) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM fuel_usage where driver_code='$driver_code' AND unit_code='$unit_code' AND fuel_type='$fuel_type' and (date between '$date_from' and '$date_to')";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        }elseif (!empty($date_from) && !empty($date_to) && empty($unit_code) && empty($driver_code) && empty($fuel_type)) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM fuel_usage where (date between '$date_from' and '$date_to') ";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        }  elseif (empty($date_from) && empty($date_to) && !empty($unit_code) && !empty($driver_code) && !empty($fuel_type)) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM fuel_usage where driver_code='$driver_code' AND unit_code='$unit_code' AND fuel_type='$fuel_type'";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        }  else {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM FUEL_USAGE";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        }
```

or try in short way

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fuel_usage where 1 ";
if (!empty($driver_code)) {
  $sql .= " AND driver_code='$driver_code' ";
} 
if (!empty($unit_code)) {
  $sql .= " AND unit_code='$unit_code' ";
} 
if (!empty($fuel_type)) {
  $sql .= " AND fuel_type='$fuel_type' ";
} 
if (!empty($date_from) && !empty($date_to)) {
  $sql .= " AND date between '$date_from' and '$date_to' ";
}
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    if (!empty($driver_code) && !empty($unit_code) && !empty($fuel_type) && !empty($date_from) && !empty($date_to)) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM fuel_usage where driver_code='$driver_code' AND unit_code='$unit_code' AND fuel_type='$fuel_type' and (date between '$date_from' and '$date_to')";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    }
    elseif(!empty ($unit_code) && !empty ($driver_code) && !empty ($fuel_type)) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM fuel_usage where driver_code='$driver_code' AND unit_code='$unit_code' AND fuel_type='$fuel_type'";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    }
    elseif (!empty($date_from) and !empty($date_to)) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM fuel_usage where (date between '$date_from' and '$date_to') ";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    }  else {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM FUEL_USAGE";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    }
```

Comment: You have simply copied @Rakesh Sharma 's answer without any explanation. Thats definetly a downvote.

Comment: My apologies. Here the explanation--- isset() function only checks that the variable is set or not .It will not check either it is empty or not but !empty() function checks whether it is empty or not. Thats why I used this function